# error while uploading project to Google App Engine(python)

Tags: python, google-app-engine, uploading

```
2009-06-30 23:36:28,483 ERROR appcfg.py:1272 An unexpected error occurred. Aborting.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Program Files\Google\google_appengine\google\appengine\tools\appcfg.py", line 1250, in DoUpload
    missing_files = self.Begin()
  File "C:\Program Files\Google\google_appengine\google\appengine\tools\appcfg.py", line 1045, in Begin
    version=self.version, payload=self.config.ToYAML())
  File "C:\Program Files\Google\google_appengine\google\appengine\tools\appengine_rpc.py", line 344, in Send
    f = self.opener.open(req)
  File "C:\Python25\lib\urllib2.py", line 387, in open
    response = meth(req, response)
  File "C:\Python25\lib\urllib2.py", line 498, in http_response
    'http', request, response, code, msg, hdrs)
  File "C:\Python25\lib\urllib2.py", line 425, in error
    return self._call_chain(*args)
  File "C:\Python25\lib\urllib2.py", line 360, in _call_chain
    result = func(*args)
  File "C:\Python25\lib\urllib2.py", line 506, in http_error_default
    raise HTTPError(req.get_full_url(), code, msg, hdrs, fp)
HTTPError: HTTP Error 403: Forbidden
Error 403: --- begin server output ---
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<HTML><HEAD><META HTTP-EQUIV="Content-Type" CONTENT="text/html; charset=gb2312">
<TITLE>The requested URL could not be retrieved</TITLE>
<STYLE type="text/css"><!--BODY{background-color:#ffffff;font-family:verdana,sans-serif}PRE{font-family:sans-serif}--></STYLE>
</HEAD><BODY>
<H3>The requested URL could not be retrieved</H3>
Please double check or try again later.
<HR noshade size="1px">

</BODY>
--- end server output ---
```

What's wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're trying to upload to a URL to which you lack access -- are you sure you're spelling your app name right, own its name on appspot, etc, etc?

Answer (score 0):

I see a HTTP 403 Forbidden in there, which says to me that your authentications is probably not sorted out correctly.

Answer (score 0):

HTTP Error 403: Forbidden... bad username/password for the given application (did you change app.yaml at all since the last successful update)?

The requested URL could not be retrieved... Or maybe they had a service interruption. Try again after a bit.